# Keystore file not found for signing config 'debug'

Tags: android, react-native

When I add the SplashActivity for my android project.

```
package com.mypackage;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

It show no error message until I compile it:

```
Keystore file '/Users/sb/Github/believingDying/DccNativeApp/android/app/debug.keystore' not found for signing config 'debug'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seems like a bug of android version, I just add the keystone file [following this guide](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25629#issuecomment-513245590).